# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS won't accept wifi password

Tags: wireless

Have installed all updates and upgrades. Wifi worked on my campus that has no wifi password, but when I attempt to connect to home network (with correct password) it waits a few seconds and finally asks for authentication again. Any tips would help!

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

First thing, make sure you don't have capslock on. After that, try again. If that doesn't work, try to do it with the wifi-menu utility. I think it's automatically installed on Ubuntu, but I'm not sure. Type in `wifimenu "your wifi-interface-name`. And try that. If that doesn't work, I don't know what will.

Comment: It's not installed by default and I can't find a manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=wifimenu

Comment: How about trying to install it while you are at your campus?